# What is the bare minimum required in the EJB client classpath?

Tags: ejb-3.0, stub

I write a remote EJB interface (3.0) and write the EJB implementation. Now I deploy the EJB as an ear on WAS. On a separate machine I write a Java client to call the EJB. In the classpath of the client, I just need to have the EJB stub?

Is there anything else required on client side? I understand as a redundancy mechanism I am supposed to put the ejb and the bean also on client but i am not considering that here.

Answer (score 1):

To call EJB from remote client you will need client libraries from application server that hosts your EJB, and EJB remote interface.

WepSphere client library name depends on server version which you are using, for v8 it will be **com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_8.0.0.jar** located in **app_server_root\runtimes** directory

Comment: So the remote interface needs to be present on client and server side, the stub needs to be present on client side only and hte actual bean needs to be present on server side only...is this right

Comment: Yes Victor, wherever you want to use Session bean, you always need to have interface (Local, Remote, or Bean class in case of no-interface view). In brief, stubs are used by remote clients, to invoke EJBs located on JNDI.